# JFrame working for a bit then stops working

Tags: java, jframe

My JFrame window pops up, and I can enter a few values and click around ~3 times before it stops allowing me to click and basically just crashes. I can't do anything with it unless I terminate the program and run it again. Then the problem repeats itself. I'm fairly positive I don't have an infinite loop running. 
Here is the code:
***Catalog class:***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Catalog {

private String name;

private ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

public Catalog(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void add(Item item) {
    this.list.add(item);
}

public int size() {
    return list.size();
}

public Item get(int index) {
    return list.get(index);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

***Item Class:***

```
public class Item {

private String name;
private double price;
private int bulkQuantity;
private double bulkPrice;
public Item(String name, double price) {
    if(price<0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price cannot be negative");
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
public Item(String name, double price, int bulkQuantity, double bulkPrice) {
    if(price<0 || bulkPrice<0 || bulkQuantity<0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price or bulkPrice or 
bulkQuantity cannot be negative");
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.bulkQuantity = bulkQuantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.bulkPrice = bulkPrice;
}

public double priceFor(int quantity) {
    if(quantity<0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity cannot be negative");
    }
    if(quantity>=bulkQuantity) {
        int numberOfBulkQuantities = 0;
        for(int i = quantity-bulkQuantity; i>=0; i-=bulkQuantity) {
            numberOfBulkQuantities++;
            quantity-=bulkQuantity;
        }
        return numberOfBulkQuantities*bulkPrice + quantity*price;
    }
    return quantity*price;
}

public String toString() {
    if(bulkPrice>0) {
        return "" + name + ", $" + price + " (" + bulkQuantity + " for $" + 
bulkPrice + ")";
    }
    return "" + name + ", $" + price;
}

}
```

***ItemOrder Class:***

```
public class ItemOrder {

private int quantity;
private Item item;
public ItemOrder(Item item, int quantity) {
    this.item = item;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return item.priceFor(quantity);
}
public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}
}
```

***ShoppingCart*** Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart {

private ArrayList<ItemOrder> list;
private double discount = 1;
public ShoppingCart() {
    list = new ArrayList<ItemOrder>();
}
public void add(ItemOrder item) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

if(list.get(i).getItem().toString().equals(item.getItem().toString())){ 
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
    list.add(item);
}
public void setDiscount(boolean discount) {
    if(discount) {
        this.discount = 0.9;
    }
}
public double getTotal() {
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        totalPrice+=list.get(i).getPrice();
    }
    return totalPrice*discount;
}
}
```

***ShoppingFrame Class:***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;

public class ShoppingFrame extends JFrame {
private ShoppingCart items;
private JTextField total;

public ShoppingFrame(Catalog products)      {
    // create frame and order list
    setTitle(products.getName());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    items = new ShoppingCart();

    // set up text field with order total
    total = new JTextField("$0.00", 12);
    total.setEditable(false);
    total.setEnabled(false);
    total.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);
    JLabel l = new JLabel("order total");
    l.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    p.add(l);
    p.add(total);
    add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(products.size(), 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++)
        addItem(products.get(i), p);
    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    p = new JPanel();
   add(makeCheckBoxPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // adjust size to just fit
    pack();
}

// Sets up the "discount" checkbox for the frame
private JPanel makeCheckBoxPanel() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);
    final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("qualify for discount");
    p.add(cb);
    cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            items.setDiscount(cb.isSelected());
            updateTotal();
        }
    });
    return p;
}

// adds a product to the panel, including a textfield for user input of
// the quantity
private void addItem(final Item product, JPanel p) {
    JPanel sub = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    sub.setBackground(new Color(0, 180, 0));
    final JTextField quantity = new JTextField(3);
    quantity.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    quantity.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateItem(product, quantity);
            quantity.transferFocus();
        }
    });
    quantity.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            updateItem(product, quantity);
        }
    });
    sub.add(quantity);
    JLabel l = new JLabel("" + product);
    l.setForeground(Color.white);
    sub.add(l);
    p.add(sub);
}

// When the user types a new value into one of the quantity fields,
// parse the input and update the ShoppingCart.  Display an error
// message if text is not a number or is negative.
private void updateItem(Item product, JTextField quantity) {
    int number;
    String text = quantity.getText().trim();
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException error) {
        number = 0;
    }
    if (number <= 0 && text.length() > 0) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        quantity.setText("");
        number = 0;
    }
    items.add(new ItemOrder(product, number));
    updateTotal();
}

// reset the text field for order total
private void updateTotal() {
    double amount = items.getTotal();
    total.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount));
}
}
```

***ShoppingMain Class:***

```
public class ShoppingMain{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Catalog list = new Catalog("CS Gift Catalog");
    list.add(new Item("silly putty", 3.95, 10, 19.99));
    list.add(new Item("silly string", 3.50, 10, 14.95));
    list.add(new Item("bottle o bubbles", 0.99));
    list.add(new Item("Nintendo Wii system", 389.99));
    list.add(new Item("Mario Computer Science Party 2 (Wii)", 49.99));
    list.add(new Item("Don Knuth Code Jam Challenge (Wii)", 49.99));
    list.add(new Item("Computer Science pen", 3.40));
    list.add(new Item("Rubik's cube", 9.10));
    list.add(new Item("Computer Science Barbie", 19.99));
    list.add(new Item("'Java Rules!' button", 0.99, 10, 5.0));
    list.add(new Item("'Java Rules!' bumper sticker", 0.99, 20, 8.95));

    ShoppingFrame f = new ShoppingFrame(list);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your application and seeing if there's a point where it locks up the CPU? Maybe there's a deadlock, or maybe there is an infinite loop. What have you done between when it worked before and when it started crashing continuously? Those are some places to start.

Comment: well clearly it's line 33 in the second file. How do you actually expect to get help? What sort of answer are you expecting given the information provided?

Comment: more likely than a loop, you are probably causing thread issues.

Comment: @MadPhysicist could you take a look again? I edited the code in. Thanks!

Comment: Please create a *minimal* example to reproduce your error. That will also help you figure out what the error actually is. Stack overflow is not a replacement for basic debugging procedure.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, OP, one thing definitely wrong is that you're using Swing on the main thread - you have to use it on the AWT Event Dispatcher thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html - Solution: Wrap all of your main method code of this example into "SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{ YOURCODEHERE });"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some head scratching debugging, your problem is in here...

```
public double priceFor(int quantity) {
    if (quantity < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity cannot be negative");
    }
    if (quantity >= bulkQuantity) {
        int numberOfBulkQuantities = 0;
        for (int i = quantity - bulkQuantity; i >= 0; i -= bulkQuantity) {
            numberOfBulkQuantities++;
            quantity -= bulkQuantity;
        }
        return numberOfBulkQuantities * bulkPrice + quantity * price;
    }
    return quantity * price;
}
```

More specifically, here...

```
for (int i = quantity - bulkQuantity; i >= 0; i -= bulkQuantity) {
    numberOfBulkQuantities++;
    quantity -= bulkQuantity;
}
```

When `bulkQuantity` is `0`, you get stuck in an infinite loop as `i -= 0` is `i`, so the loop will never exit

So, a little change to something like...

```
if (quantity >= bulkQuantity && bulkQuantity > 0) {
    int numberOfBulkQuantities = 0;
    for (int i = quantity - bulkQuantity; i >= 0; i -= bulkQuantity) {
        numberOfBulkQuantities++;
        quantity -= bulkQuantity;
    }
    return numberOfBulkQuantities * bulkPrice + quantity * price;
}
```

will allow the program to continue operating